# Two pointers with the same derived type

Tags: pointers, types, fortran, derived

I tried to create two different derived types within the same module but it didn't work (tried to put x and y pointers as different derived type). I shifted to this code instead. Here is a generic Fortran sample of it:
(Error: program is crashing)

```
  module one
    implicit none

    type one
      logical :: first_entry
      integer :: value
      integer, pointer :: next
    end type one

    type(one), dimension(:), pointer :: x 
    type(one), dimension(:), pointer :: y 

  end module one

  module two 
    use one

    implicit none

    y(:)%first_entry = .true.

    do k = 1, 10

      if(y(k)%first_entry) then 
          ...do things
          y(k)%next => x(k)%value
      end if

    end do

  end module two
```

Here is a sample of the original code I was trying. for example I have 10 boxes and I want 100 sands in each of the 10 boxes. In each box, I want a pointer to point towards the first sand by their id but sand should be linked to one another in a linked list.

```
module one
    implicit none

    type sand
      integer :: id
      integer, pointer :: next
    end type sand

    type box
      logical :: first_entry
      integer :: id
      integer, pointer :: first
    end type box

    type(sand), dimension(:), pointer :: s 
    type(box), dimension(:), pointer :: b 

  end module one

  module two 
    use one

    implicit none
    integer :: k

    ! Initialize 
    b%first_entry = .true.

    ! For each sand 
    do j = 1, 100
      ! for each 10 boxes, point to first sand by id and link all
      ! the sand%next to point to the next sand%id
      do k = 1, 10
        if(b(k)%first_entry) then 
          b(k)%first => s(j)%id
          b(k)%first_entry = .false.
        else
          s(j)%next => s(j+1)%id
          ...some condition to detect end of list
        end if
      end do
    end do

  end module two
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How is it crashing? Does it write anything? How are you compiling it? Which compiler? Which options/flags?

Comment: So which code crashes? This one or some other code? If some other code, you should show that one. It is not clear to me from your description.

Comment: `y(:)%first_entry = .true.` but `y` is set to `null()` isn't it? Or is is set to something else? Please supply a [mcve]

Comment: At some point (before `y(:)%...`) you're going to have to allocate `y` or point it to a target.  It isn't exactly clear to me what you are trying to do (beyond implementing a linked list), so I won't suggest how to do that.

Comment: @VladimirF it is compiling. But the program is being killed at run time.

Comment: I set it to null() only because I read that it is always good practice to null a pointer when defining it.

Comment: @VladimirF Please see below the original sample and intent of the code that i want. thank you for responding. i hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @francescalus Please see below the original sample and intent of the code that i want. thank you for responding. i hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: It is still not very clear. Which of the codes is crashing? What does it *exactly* print? How do you allocate `y(:)` so that it is null? It **must not be null**!

Comment: Both codes are crashing. The original one (second code) is the one that I originally wanted but changed to the first code because the first code at least compiled. The original/second code is the one describing more clearly my intent. When I remove the nulls and I am still getting the same error: forrtl: error (78): process killed (SIGTERM). I allocated memory for "next" and "value" but not for the pointers since they are only pointing to next and value. Am i getting that concept wrong?

Comment: Who knows, please supply the whole program that we can try. Otherwise we don't know what you are actually doing. **But just deleting the `=> null()` surely cannot help!!!** It is a good thing!!! But the point is the memory must be allocated. In the main program that we have to see. We have see how are the subroutines in the module being used.